# Run ASP.NET Core Project from Visual Studio 2017

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-core

I have created ASP.NET Core project from command line:

```
> dotnet new web
> dotnet restore
> dotnet build
> dotnet run
```

All works fine.

Now I have opened this project in Visual Studio 2017.

- Debug - Start without debugging:

> Unhandled Exception: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load
>   file or assembly 'System.Runtime, Version=4.1.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The
>   system cannot find the file specified.    at
>   System.ModuleHandle.ResolveType(RuntimeModule module, Int32 typeToken,
>   IntPtr* typeInstArgs, Int32 typeInstCount, IntPtr* methodInstArgs,
>   Int32 methodInstCount, ObjectHandleOnStack type)    at
>   System.ModuleHandle.ResolveTypeHandleInternal(RuntimeModule module,
>   Int32 typeToken, RuntimeTypeHandle[] typeInstantiationContext,
>   RuntimeTypeHandle[] methodInstantiationContext)    at
>   System.Reflection.RuntimeModule.ResolveType(Int32 metadataToken,
>   Type[] genericTypeArguments, Type[] genericMethodArguments)    at
>   System.Reflection.CustomAttribute.FilterCustomAttributeRecord(CustomAttributeRecord
>   caRecord, MetadataImport scope, Assembly& lastAptcaOkAssembly,
>   RuntimeModule decoratedModule, MetadataToken decoratedToken,
>   RuntimeType attributeFilterType, Boolean mustBeInheritable, Object[]
>   attributes, IList derivedAttributes, RuntimeType& attributeType,
>   IRuntimeMethodInfo& ctor, Boolean& ctorHasParameters, Boolean&
>   isVarArg)    at
>   System.Reflection.CustomAttribute.GetCustomAttributes(RuntimeModule
>   decoratedModule, Int32 decoratedMetadataToken, Int32 pcaCount,
>   RuntimeType attributeFilterType, Boolean mustBeInheritable, IList
>   derivedAttributes, Boolean isDecoratedTargetSecurityTransparent)    at
>   System.Reflection.CustomAttribute.GetCustomAttributes(RuntimeAssembly
>   assembly, RuntimeType caType)    at
>   System.Attribute.GetCustomAttributes(Assembly element, Type
>   attributeType, Boolean inherit)    at
>   System.AppDomain.GetTargetFrameworkName()

How can I launcn, debug and develop my project in VS ?

p.s. I know I can create new project in VS and it works fine, but I need to work with project which was created from command line.

*Update:*

```
PS Q:\tsts> dotnet --version
1.0.0

PS Q:\tsts> type .\tsts.csproj
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp1.1</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <Folder Include="wwwroot\" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore" Version="1.1.1" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>


PS Q:\tsts> dotnet build
Microsoft (R) Build Engine version 15.1.548.43366
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

  tsts -> Q:\tsts\bin\Debug\netcoreapp1.1\tsts.dll

Build succeeded.
    0 Warning(s)
    0 Error(s)

Time Elapsed 00:00:02.90
```

Comment: What is `dotnetcore` command? Maybe `dotnet`? Run `dotnet --version` and `dotnet` and show output (from `dotnet` - only version and build)? And add your `csproj` file please.

Comment: I have updated the question.

Comment: Repeated your steps - VS2017 opened and runned project successfully, both via IIS Express and via project run ('Run' button dropdown). Check that "dependencies" in solution explorer are ok (no yellow signs about package restore problems). Try close VS, remove `bin`, `obj` and `.vs` folder and reopen - VS will re-restore packages.

Comment: Thanks. Removing `bin` and `obj` folders helped me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Opening and running `dotnet new` project in VS2017 should work.

But sometimes VS goes crazy with strange and inexplicable "not found" dependencies and "not compiled" new files - then just close VS (or unload project), manually remove `bin` and `obj` folders and reopen project.